# What's the better-practice way to rotate a string by one character in Python?

Tags: python

I'm doing a codecademy task and was wondering which of the following set of code is considered best practice:

The task is to create a function, given a string username , that shifts all letters one to the right.
For example the username : AbeSimp would become pAbeSim, this becomes the password and is stored in the string password.

Here is my code:

```
def password_generator(username):
    password = ""
    password = username[-1] + username[:-1]
    return password
```

The Solution code is :

```
def password_generator(username):
    password = ""
    for i in range(0, len(user_name)):
       password += user_name[i-1]
    return password
```

Any explanation is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: The solution is not idiomatic python. `range(0, len...))` alone makes my eye twitch.

Comment: "Best practice" questions are explicitly too opinion-centric to be considered topical here. See [Why is asking a question on best practice a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing) on [meta.se].

Comment: `password_generator = lambda username: username[-1] + user[:-1]` is the best one liner I can think of right now

Comment: (Also, a good question title *describes the individual question*. "Basic Python question" doesn't say anything about the question that the Python tag itself doesn't; ideally, you should try to make the title so descriptive that someone can know if they have the same problem -- and thus will be helped by the answers that help you -- by the title alone).

Comment: The so-called solution with its inefficient building of the string one char at a time, the indices manipulation and the trick to get -1 is a good example of what not to do.

Answer (score 2):

IMO the best-practice version of this would be:

```
def password_generator(username: str) -> str:
    """Generate a terrible password by rotating the username."""
    return username[-1] + username[:-1]
```

Get rid of dead code.  Don't make an assignment you're going to overwrite.  Don't use a loop where a slice will do.  And if a variable isn't going to be used more than one place (e.g. in a `return` statement), no point even giving it a name IMO.

Comment: The documentation is a nice touch!

Comment: I like how this works thanks! The string you have put in there is just a joke  right? it contributes nothing to the code or am i misunderstood

Comment: It's a "docstring", i.e. a string that describes what the function does; it's similar to a comment, but you can actually fetch a docstring programmatically via an expression like `password_generator.__doc__`.  It's generally recommended that any public function should have a docstring so that users of that function can get an idea of what it's meant to do without having to read the implementation.

Comment: Potential error cases are the most important thing to document -- for example, saying what non-obvious exceptions might be raised for certain use cases, and especially any caveats about security weaknesses (like if you have a function called `password_generator`, you definitely want to document how "strong" the password is so the caller knows how safe it is to use).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. I am wondering where would you get that solution, which doesn't seem to be correct in terms of efficiency or syntactically. As there additional complexity of for-loop involved.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you are asking i think I just have the code that you need.

```
from random import shuffle

def password_generator(username):
    username = list(username)
    shuffle(username)
    return ''.join(username)
print(password_generator('THIS-IS-USERNAME'))
```

the output I got is:

```
SNE--SSHIATIRMEU

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It changed `THIS-IS-USERNAME` to `SNE--SSHIATIRMEU`

hope this helps you

Comment: Please don't have everything in capitals. It's jarring, harder to read, and native English speakers often interpret capitals as aggressive and imitating shouting. I don't know if that's why you were downvoted, but it's a possible reason.

Comment: ohh sorry will surely not do this again